# Ionic/AngularJS - ng-include update too fast?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular, and I want to learn it along with developing my app, but I don't know what is going on in this part :

I have service which is handling XMPP library (with own event handlers), and to connect it with controllers I chosen $broadcast, because I need something flexible. After creating connection, app is switching to controller in which I want to display template according to connection status, what looks like :

```
$scope.$on('status:changed',function(e,status){
   scopeTemplate = null;
   switch(status){
      case Connecting :
         scopeTemplate = 'templates/connection_waiting.html';
         break;
      case Connected :
         $state.go('main');
         break;
      case AuthError :
          scopeTemplate = 'templates/connecting_autherror.html';
          break;
      ...
  }
  $scope.template = scopeTemplate;
});
```

and ng-include inside parent template :

```
<ion-view view-title='Connecting' name='connecting-view'>
   <ion-content layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <ng-include src ="template"></ng-include>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When XMPP connect function fires, controller receives status Connecting, and load animation is showing up, or when I'm connected, app is switching to another state, but strange things have place, when controllers receives AuthErrror. Then in most cases template is not updating, but very rarely it does, So I'm wondering is it my fault somewhere, or what, and what should I do to make this working every time.

Comment: are you checking .. `AuthError` as variable? or as string? maybe missing `"`?

Comment: It's just an example, but it is a lib constant.

Comment: In this snippet, i cannot find any mistakes.., just misnamed variabled: `scopeTemplate , temp`, but i think in your app you spelled it right

Comment: I don't get it. When I tried to fb, or my jabber server it's not switiching, but when connecting to google, its working.

Comment: hm... where did you define `var temp`?

Comment: ohh ,misstyped scopeTemplate should be temp var. After digging i thing its not a Angular issue, but library ;/

Comment: ok, then my thought 2 comments above was right :D missnamed... does it work now?

Comment: It still don't work at all with fb, and my server, and don't work with google if server response is really fast.